# I get a NullPointerException while trying to fill a TableView (JavaFX) and i dont know why

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I got a NullPointerException while trying to populate a tableView and i have no idea why... 
The Exception gets thrown at `column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<T, S>("s"))`

Has someone an idea where the error is? Here are some parts of my code:

controller.java:

```
@FXML
private TableView<TagebuchEintrag> tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TagebuchEintrag, LocalDate> datumColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TagebuchEintrag, Long> dauerColumn;

@FXML
protected void handleLogInAction(final ActionEvent event) 
        throws IOException, MissingDAOException, MissingPatientIdException{

    String username = logInUsername.getText();
    String password = logInPwField.getText();

    int id = Authenticator.getInstance().validateUser(username, password);
    if(id != -1l){
        BewegungsTagebuch.setPatientenId(id);
        bewegungsTagebuch = BewegungsTagebuch.getInstance();

        Stage stage = (Stage) login.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainApplication.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene (root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(bewegungsTagebuch.getTagebuchEintraege());
        initialize();
        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
    else{
        logInUsername.clear();
        logInPwField.clear();
        Stage stage = (Stage)login.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.hide();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falsche Kennwort Kombination!", "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        stage.show();
    }
}

BewegungsTagebuch bewegungsTagebuch;
final ObservableList<TagebuchEintrag> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private void initialize() {

    if(bewegungsTagebuch != null && BewegungsTagebuch.getPatientenId() > -1){

        datumColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TagebuchEintrag, LocalDate>("start"));

        dauerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TagebuchEintrag, Long>("dauer"));
}}
```

MainApplication.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mainAnchorPanel1" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="839.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GuiController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="839.0">
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Optionen">
        <items>
          <MenuItem fx:id="abmelden" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLogOutAction" text="Log Out" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="beenden" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseAction" text="Beenden" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bearbeiten">
           <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="neuerEintrag" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNeuerEintragAction" text="Neuer Eintrag" />
           </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
  <ScrollPane layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="516.0" prefWidth="839.0">
    <content>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="824.0">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="tableView" editable="true" prefHeight="516.0" prefWidth="824.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="9.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="datumColumn" prefWidth="141.0" sortable="false" text="Datum" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="dauerColumn" prefWidth="87.0" sortable="false" text="Dauer" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="artBewegungColumn" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="117.0" sortable="false" text="Art der Bewegung" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="belastungColumn" prefWidth="174.0" sortable="false" text="Belastungsgrad" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="schmerzColumn" prefWidth="145.0" sortable="false" text="Schmerz bei Bewegung" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="wohlbefindenColumn" prefWidth="159.0" sortable="false" text="Wohlbefinden" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </content>
  </ScrollPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

TagebuchEintrag.java:

```
private final int patientId;
private final int tagebuchEintragId;
private final LongProperty dauer;
private final ObjectProperty<Belastungsgrad> belastungsgrad;
private final ObjectProperty<BewegungsArt> bewegungsArt;
private final ObjectProperty<Bewegungsschmerz> bewegungsschmerz;
private final ObjectProperty<Wohlbefinden> wohlbefinden;
private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> start;
private LocalDate ende;

private static int counter;

public TagebuchEintrag(int patientId, Belastungsgrad belastungsgrad, BewegungsArt bewegungsArt, 
        Bewegungsschmerz bewegungsschmerz, Wohlbefinden wohlbefinden, LocalDate start, LocalDate ende){

    this.patientId = patientId;
    this.belastungsgrad = new SimpleObjectProperty<Belastungsgrad>(belastungsgrad);
    this.bewegungsArt = new SimpleObjectProperty<BewegungsArt>(bewegungsArt);
    this.bewegungsschmerz = new SimpleObjectProperty<Bewegungsschmerz>(bewegungsschmerz);
    this.wohlbefinden = new SimpleObjectProperty<Wohlbefinden>(wohlbefinden);
    this.start = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(start);
    this.ende = ende;
    dauer = new SimpleLongProperty(ende.toEpochDay() - start.toEpochDay());
    tagebuchEintragId = counter;
    counter++;
}

//Getter+Setter
```

The observable list is not empty, I checked on that, and the object in the list is filled with data aswell, so I dont know where my problem is. All java codes here are shortend for the sake of simplicity. I did some googling and neither of the answers helped me...

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.GuiController.initialize(GuiController.java:204)
at application.GuiController.handleLogInAction(GuiController.java:160)
... 58 more
```

Line 204 is the call on `datumColum.setCellValueFactory` and the `start` is not empty.

Comment: The stacktrace told you where the error is. Please provide it in the question

Comment: `datumColumn` seems to be null. The exception probably tells you that it tried to call methods `setCellValueFactor` on a null value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX, why is TableColumn null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463788/javafx-why-is-tablecolumn-null) Not sure you can call `initialize` yourself (don't use JavaFx a lot...)

Comment: That is actually the problem, thank you! My columns are not initiated, therefor the methods wont work... Now I just need a way to fix this :|